# How to notify parent component of property change when using react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Lets say I have a parent component and child component. The parent component is composed of several child components. The parent component holds and manages a very complex and deep data object. Each child component provides the UI to manage various child objects and properties of the main data object. Whenever the child component changes a property value in the data object hierarchy, that change needs to bubble up to the main data object.

Here is how I might do it in a child component class by passing in a callback object...

```
<div>
  <button onClick={e => this.setState({propA: e.target.value}, () => props.onChangePropA(this.state.propA)}>Prop A</button>
  <button onClick={e => this.setState({propB: e.target.value}, () => props.onChangePropB(this.state.propB)}>Prop B</button>
</div>
```

Versus how I think I need to do it using hooks. The main problem I'm seeing is that there is no callback option for after the state change has completed. So I have to detect it in the useEffect and figure out which property just changed...

```
let prevPropA = props.propA;
let prevPropB = props.propB;

const [propA, setPropA] = useState(props.propA);
const [propB, setPropB] = useState(props.propB);

useEffect(() => { 
  if (prevPropA != propA) props.onChangePropA(propA); 
  if (prevPropB != propB) props.onChangePropB(propB); 
});

<div>
  <button onClick={e => {prevPropA = propA; setPropA(e.target.value)}}>Prop A</button>
  <button onClick={e => {prevPropB = propB; setPropB(e.target.value)}}>Prop B</button>
</div>
```

I see this method getting extremely cumbersome and messy. Is there a more robust/proper way to accomplish this?

Thanks

=============================================================

Below is updated sample code based on Shubham's answer and
Ryan's feedback. Shubham answered the question as asked, but
Ryan is suggesting I give a more thorough example to ensure
I'm giving the right info for the right answer.
Here is sample code that more closely follows my real world
situation... although still a simplified example.
The parent component manages comments from users. Imagine
they can create new comments and select a date or a date-range.
They can also update existing comments. I have put the date
and date-range selector in its own component.
Therefore the parent comment manager component needs the ability
to create/load comments and pass the associated date(s) down to the
date-selector component. The user can then change the date(s)
and those values need to be propagated back up to the parent comment
manager to later be sent to the server and saved.
So you see, there is a bidirectional flow of property values (dates, etc)
that can be changed at any time from either end.
NOTE: This new example is updated using a method similar to what
Shubham suggested based on my original question.

=============================================================

```
const DateTimeRangeSelector = (props) =>
{
    const [contextDateStart, setContextDateStart] = useState(props.contextDateStart);
    const [contextDateEnd, setContextDateEnd] = useState(props.contextDateEnd);
    const [contextDateOnly, setContextDateOnly] = useState(props.contextDateOnly);
    const [contextDateHasRange, setContextDateHasRange] = useState(props.contextDateHasRange);

    useEffect(() => { setContextDateStart(props.contextDateStart);  }, [ props.contextDateStart  ]);
    useEffect(() => { if (contextDateStart !== undefined) props.onChangeContextDateStart(contextDateStart);  }, [ contextDateStart  ]);

    useEffect(() => { setContextDateEnd(props.contextDateEnd);  }, [ props.contextDateEnd  ]);
    useEffect(() => { if (contextDateEnd !== undefined) props.onChangeContextDateEnd(contextDateEnd); }, [ contextDateEnd  ]);

    useEffect(() => { setContextDateOnly(props.contextDateOnly);  }, [ props.contextDateOnly  ]);
    useEffect(() => { if (contextDateOnly !== undefined) props.onChangeContextDateOnly(contextDateOnly); }, [ contextDateOnly  ]);

    useEffect(() => { setContextDateHasRange(props.contextDateHasRange); }, [ props.contextDateHasRange  ]);
    useEffect(() => { if (contextDateHasRange !== undefined) props.onChangeContextDateHasRange(contextDateHasRange);  }, [ contextDateHasRange  ]);


    return <div>
    <ToggleButtonGroup 
        exclusive={false}
        value={(contextDateHasRange === true) ? ['range'] : []}
        selected={true}
        onChange={(event, value) => setContextDateHasRange(value.some(item => item === 'range'))}
        >
        <ToggleButton value='range' title='Specify a date range'  > 
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon='arrows-alt-h' size='lg' />
        </ToggleButton>
    </ToggleButtonGroup>

    {
        (contextDateHasRange === true)
        ?
        <DateTimeRangePicker 
            range={[contextDateStart, contextDateEnd]} 
            onChangeRange={val => { setContextDateStart(val[0]); setContextDateEnd(val[1]);  }}
            onChangeShowTime={ val => setContextDateOnly(! val) }
            />
        :
        <DateTimePicker
            selectedDate={contextDateStart} 
            onChange={val => setContextDateStart(val)}
            showTime={! contextDateOnly}
        />

    }
</div>
}


const CommentEntry = (props) =>
{
    const [activeComment, setActiveComment] = useState(null);

    const createComment = () =>
    {
        return {uid: uuidv4(), content: '', contextDateHasRange: false,  contextDateOnly: false, contextDateStart: null, contextDateEnd: null};
    }

    const editComment = () =>
    {
        return loadCommentFromSomewhere();
    }

    const newComment = () =>
    {
        setActiveComment(createComment());
    }

    const clearComment = () =>
    {
        setActiveComment(null);
    }

    return (
    <div>

        <Button onClick={() => newComment()} variant="contained">
            New Comment
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={() => editComment()} variant="contained">
            Edit Comment
        </Button>

        {
            activeComment !== null &&
            <div>
                <TextField
                    value={(activeComment) ? activeComment.content: ''}
                    label="Enter comment..."
                    onChange={(event) => { setActiveComment({...activeComment, content: event.currentTarget.value, }) }}
                />
                <DateTimeRangeSelector

                    onChange={(val) => setActiveComment(val)}

                    contextDateStart={activeComment.contextDateStart}
                    onChangeContextDateStart={val => activeComment.contextDateStart = val}

                    contextDateEnd={activeComment.contextDateEnd}
                    onChangeContextDateEnd={val => activeComment.contextDateEnd = val}

                    contextDateOnly={activeComment.contextDateOnly}
                    onChangeContextDateOnly={val => activeComment.contextDateOnly = val}

                    contextDateHasRange={activeComment.contextDateHasRange}
                    onChangeContextDateHasRange={val => activeComment.contextDateHasRange = val}

                    />
                <Button onClick={() => clearComment()} variant="contained">
                    Cancel
                </Button>
                <Button color='primary' onClick={() => httpPostJson('my-url', activeComment, () => console.log('saved'))} variant="contained" >
                    <SaveIcon/> Save
                </Button>
            </div>
        }    
    </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: In this example, what is `e.target.value`? The button doesn't have a value, so I'm assuming this would actually be a value that would come from some other input managed by the child?

Comment: What is the reason (in the non-hook example) for passing `onChangePropA` as a callback to `setState`? Why not just call it immediately? I assume it is updating part of the complex state of the parent. I'm not sure why you would update this value in two places. I would expect the button to update the parent and then the parent pass the updated value through as a prop to the child rather than the child also having it in its own state.

Comment: @RyanCogswell, you are correct on both counts. Sloppy pseudo-code I guess. I was just trying to get across a more general point.

Comment: It may be worth updating your question to more accurately reflect what you are trying to do -- including a simple version of the parent. I don't think `useEffect` is necessarily a good match for what you are trying to do, but I would need to see a more realistic representation of the full picture to know what would be appropriate.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Done. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: So `CommentEntry` is your parent and `DateTimeRangeSelector` is the child. Should every change to the child state also update the parent state immediately or is there a separate action in the child that should cause the two to sync up? I see an `onChange` prop being passed to the child that does the actual state update, but it doesn't seem to be used. The more specific `onChange...` methods are mutating the state, but not actually calling the state's setter which could lead to some confusing behavior.

Comment: "I see an onChange prop being passed to the child that does the actual state update, but it doesn't seem to be used."
I have a hybrid of multiple child and grandchild components going on. In this particular case, that 'grandchild' component is maintaining its own state and child component is simply passing the new property value up to the parent. It's just passing it up the chain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187601/discussion-between-ryan-cogswell-and-jim-ott).

Comment: "The more specific onChange... methods are mutating the state, but not actually calling the state's setter which could lead to some confusing behavior."

Yeah, I'm mutating properties of the top level data object (the Comment object) directly. I don't see any point in re-creating the entire object tree and causing the whole thing to re-render... and again re-setting the property values of a child component that just bubbled the changes up to the top.
I'm probably doing it all wrong. I don't know. lol. But this actually works for me.

Comment: Since this was mainly a hooks learning exercise for you, you may find [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/3l498r6x6) interesting/helpful. I created a version of this when first looking at your question initially just playing around with a custom hook to manage multiple child properties in parent state.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`useEffect` takes a second argument which denotes when to execute the effect. You can pass in the state value to it so that it executes when state updates. Also you can have multiple `useEffect` hooks in your code

```
const [propA, setPropA] = useState(props.propA);
const [propB, setPropB] = useState(props.propB);

useEffect(() => { 
  props.onChangePropA(propA); 
}, [propA]);

useEffect(() => { 
  props.onChangePropB(propB); 
}, [propB]);
<div>
  <button onClick={e => {setPropA(e.target.value)}}>Prop A</button>
  <button onClick={e => {setPropB(e.target.value)}}>Prop B</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is close to doing the desired behavior, but it would have the effect of executing `onChangePropA` and `onChangePropB` after the initial render before any changes have actually occurred.

Comment: Shubham, thanks for the response. I was using this method for other things. Don't know why I didn't think to use it here. @RyanCogswell, you are right, but I'm able to work around it by conditionally executing it with something like... if (propA !== undefined). All in all it still seems like a lot of annoying boilerplate code... but I suppose much better than where I was headed.